# Failing to add a custom font to draw using HTML 5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So what I'm trying to do is try loading a custom font to use a title text in my HTML canvas.

So this is what I tried. I have a render function that draws all text.

I want to solve all rendering inside a class. So I did this:

```
class ResultSegment {

   // Information properties. 
   segmentTitle =  "";

   // Drawing specifications. Should be overwritten. 
   x = 0;
   y = 0;
   w = 100;
   y = 100;

   fontReferenceValueEM = 3;

   /**
    * Draws the segment values. 
    */
   render(ctx) {

      ctx.fillStyle = "#eeeeee";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);

      // Font color
      ctx.fillStyle = "#505150";

      let f = new FontFace('TitleFont', 'url(assets/fonts/GothamBold.otf)');

      f.load().then(this.drawTitle(ctx));      
    
   }

   drawTitle(ctx){
      // Ready to use the font in a canvas context      
      ctx.textBaseline = "top";
      ctx.font = this.fontReferenceValueEM + "em TitleFont"
      ctx.fillText(this.segmentTitle,this.x,this.y);        
   }

}
```

I don't get any errors (in the browser console, I mean) but no font is loaded or I'm calling it wrong. Using TitleFont or serif uses the exact same (default) font.

In case it wasn't obvious ctx is the 2D context of a canvas object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First thing I notice is you `fillRect()` with this.h but you don’t have a this.h in the constructor. You used this.y twice. Not sure if that’s the only problem the first noticeable one without running the code.

Comment: You are right about the h. But the code worked anyway because they are set elsewhere. The y is defined as zero up top. Thanks anyways!!